# KMP project runs but has no autocompletion in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a KMP project (SwiftUI and Compose for UI) that builds and runs successfully. Xcode has full autocompletion for SwiftUI and all of my own code + dependencies *except* for the shared KMP module. When I import it, I get no errors or warning flags and have no tooling in any scope that uses it. If the code is correct, it still compiles and I can use my shared module.

Seeing as the project builds and runs successfully, and tooling works in all other instances, I'm at a loss for how to debug this. I've done the classics:

- cmd + shift + K
- delete Derived Data
- `./gradlew clean build`
- restart Xcode
- different Xcode version
- reclone project
- try different machine

Update: Still having this problem. My best guess is that indexing goes wrong somewhere. I noticed that after `cmd + shift + K`, I very briefly get correct inference on KMP types. Then Xcode reindexes and everything becomes `<<error type>>` again.

Comment: In the meantime I've migrated the project from Android Studio to Fleet, which supports Swift. I have autocompletion for the shared module in Swift now. Would still love to use Xcode but never found a way to resolve the issue.